# Accord du champ nationalité dans les documents administratifs

Tags: usage, genre, accord

Lorsque l'on doit remplir des documents administratifs, il est souvent demandé notre nationalité. Comment devons nous remplir l'information lorsque l'on est un homme français ?

> Nationalité : Français

ou

> Nationalité : Française

Bien évidemment, la question ne se pose pas pour une femme française.

Comment: Cette question s'applique à toutes les nationalités.

Comment: Non, pas si on est belge, bulgare, chypriote, guatémaltèque, russe, suisse...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Il me semble plus correct d'utiliser

> Nationalité : Française

En effet ici l'adjectif s'accorde en genre avec *nationalité*. On peut d'ailleurs remarquer que sur le devant d'une carte d'identité française, on trouve en haut à droite la mention « Nationalité Française » quel que soit le genre de la personne.

De plus dans ce type de documents administratifs si la connaissance du genre de la personne est nécessaire il y aura un champ supplémentaire concernant cet aspect.

Comment: Merci Valram pour cette bonne réponse.

Answer (score 5):

Sur une carte d'identité :

> CARTE NATIONALE D’IDENTITÉ N° :  xxx Nationalité Française.

On répond donc à la question de *Nationalité* et non au sexe de la personne, ce qui par ailleurs serait enfreindre la part *Égalité* de la devise "*Liberté, Égalité, Fraternité*".

Comment: Tu m'expliques le coup de l'égalité ? Je vois pas… Qui pourrait bien être pénalisé par le simple fait que quelqu'un dévoile son genre ?

Comment: Il y a en France, actuellement, un grand effort pour l'égalité salariale des hommes et des femmes, une lutte contre le port du voile signe de la femme tenue pour mineure, et bien d'autres manifestations revendiquant l'égalité de droit des êtres sans tenir compte de leurs chromosomes. Affirmer que la nationalité est un homme, au-delà de l'incompatibilité du genre lexical, devient une revendication inconsciente ou un automatisme d'un machisme dépassé. Et logiquement il y aurait alors deux nationalités pour un seul pays: la *Nationalité Français* et la *Nationalité Française* (de seconde zone ?)

Answer (score 2):

Vu qu'à l'entrée *sexe* on répond généralement *femme* ou *homme* et non *masculin* ou *féminin*, l'idée qu'il s'agit ici d'un adjectif qualifiant *nationalité* ne me semble pas être d'une force telle qu'elle permette d'éliminer comme incorrecte l'autre possibilité.

Je propose donc:

> Nationalité : française

ou

> Nationalité : Français

au choix, en faisant attention aux majuscules.

(Personnellement, étant Belge, je n'ai même pas à faire attention à la majuscule ;-))

Comment: Sur la carte d'identité française la nationalité est mentionnée avec la casse suivante « Nationalité Française » (voir http://www.cil.cnrs.fr/CIL/spip.php?article1938 par exemple)

Comment: L'usage erroné n'engage pas la règle d'origine. On répond plus souvent H et F. Pour ma part je positionne l'adjectif, sinon il faudrait répondre phallus ou vulve .. ce qui peut être amusant en *belgitude*

Comment: Si l'usage et la règle sont en contradiction, j'ai tendance à être pour l'usage, sauf en ce qui concerne les majuscules abusives données aux adjectifs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

À ma connaissance il serait préférable de dire, par exemple, *de la nationalité "congolais"*, parce que cette nationalité ne s'accorde pas selon le genre de la nationalité mais plutôt de l'attachement de la personne vis-à-vis de cette nationalité et donc en fonction du lien d'attachement.

Comment: Voulez-vous dire : *congolais de nationalité* ?

Answer (score 0):

On doit écrire:
Nationalité: Français pour un homme 
Nationalité: Française pour une femme 
Dans un formulaire  le mot sous-entend la question: quelle est votre nationalité et la réponse est je suis Français ou je suis Française. L'adjectif français ou française est attribut du sujet je qui est donc omis pour simplier le formulaire et s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec le sujet.
Par contre  on dit  : avoir la nationalité française ou de nationalité française , c ' est un adjectif qui est épithète du mot nationalité et qui s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec lui.
C'est une erreur que  commet la majorité des Français .
Chez moi en Haïti certaines personnes en font pareillement.

Comment: Bien que je sois un homme, j'écris « Nationalité : Français**e** »

Comment: Ce raisonnement part d'un faux présupposé en ce qui concerne la France. Les formulaires en France ne posent pas de question, ils demandent de qualifier la nationalité. L'accord se fait avec « nationalité ». La nationalité est française.  En Haïti je ne connais pas les mœurs donc je ne dis rien sur la part de la réponse concernant votre pays.